# Ruby: array is being passed by reference into function?

Tags: arrays, ruby, pass-by-reference

I have a simple code below

```
    def testarray
      arr_tree = [1,2,3,4,5]
      (1..3).each do |index|
        abcde(arr_tree)
        puts arr_tree[0]
      end
    end

    def abcde(node_tree)
      node_tree[0] += 100
    end
```

So inside testarray function, I have an array `arr_tree` which is being passed to a function `abcde`. I change the value of the array inside `abcde` function and print array inside `testarray` I get the changed value here. So the output is

```
101
201
301
```

but I was expecting

```
1
1
1
```

Please explain why the results are like this? Also how can I achieve my expected result?

Answer (score 6):

Everything is "passed as an object" in Ruby.

And arrays are objects.

If you want to avoid side-effects make a copy of the argument

```
def abcde(node_tree)
  copy = node_tree.dup
  copy[0] += 100
  copy
end
```

A note of caution though since you named your variable `tree`, the `dup` method makes a shallow copy only. Shallow means that the array is copied but not its elements.

Why did I not say "pass by reference" above?

"Pass by reference" is a concept from another language and does not make sense in the context of Ruby. Technically the native implementation of Ruby uses pass by value, where the value is a pointer to an object structure. However thinking of Ruby as using "pass by value" is misleading since it does not create a copy of data structures before they are passed to a function. Which seems to be what you assumed would happen…

Comment: "pass by reference" means that _assigning_ another value to the variable would also change the variable in the caller's scope, e.g. `node_tree = []`. This is something Ruby doesn't allow.

Comment: Sorry, but this is wrong. Ruby is not pass by reference.

Comment: When you say "pass by reference" in Ruby, it means you try to apply a C++ concept to the wrong language.

Comment: It's still wrong to write passed by reference, even in quotes.

Comment: Point taken, both of you, updated.

Answer (score 2):

Your assumption is wrong: [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) is *not* [pass-by-reference](/questions/tagged/pass-by-reference), it is strictly [pass-by-value](/questions/tagged/pass-by-value), always. You can easily verify this by running this simple test:

```
def foo(bar)
  bar = 'reference'
end

baz = 'value'

foo(baz)

puts "Ruby is pass-by-#{baz}"
# Ruby is pass-by-value
```

More precisely, Ruby is [call-by-object-sharing](/questions/tagged/call-by-object-sharing) (also known as *call-by-object* and *call-by-sharing*), which is a special case of *pass-by-value*, where the *value* that is passed is always a pointer to a (potentially) shared (potentially) mutable object:

```
def is_ruby_pass_by_value?(foo)
  foo.replace('More precisely, it is call-by-object-sharing!')
  foo = 'No, Ruby is pass-by-reference.'
end

bar = 'Yes, of course, Ruby *is* pass-by-value!'

is_ruby_pass_by_value?(bar)

p bar
# 'More precisely, it is call-by-object-sharing!'
```

However, that is actually irrelevant to your question. It has nothing to do with *pass-by-reference* vs. *pass-by-value*.

> So inside testarray function, I have an array `arr_tree` which is being passed to a function `abcde`. I change the value of the array inside `abcde` function and print array inside `testarray` I get the changed value here.

You get the changed value because you change the value. It's as simple as that. Ruby is not a pure functional programming language, it *does* have mutable state. And if you mutate that state, then the old state is gone and only the new state exists.

You wrote yourself:

> I change the value of the array

Well, if you change the array, the array changes! There is only one array in your entire code.

> Please explain why the results are like this?

The array changes because you change the array.

> Also how can I achieve my expected result?

You can achieve your result by not changing the array:

```
def testarray
  arr_tree = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  (1..3).each do |index|
    abcde(arr_tree)
    puts arr_tree[0]
  end
end

def abcde(node_tree)
  [node_tree.first + 100, *node_tree.drop(1)]
end
```